# Java get First and Last duplicate elements of List

Tags: java, arraylist

In my application i want to get first and repetitive elements from array
eg,

```
String[] strings = {"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"
                , "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two"
                , "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three"
                , "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four"
                , "five", "five", "five", "five", "five", "five"
                , "six", "six", "six", "six", "six", "six", "six", "six", "six"
                , "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven"
                , "eight", "eight", "eight", "eight", "eight", "eight"
                , "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine"
                , "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten"};
```

for the above list i want to get output like
one
one
two
two
three
three
four
four
five
five
six
six
seven
seven
eight
eight
nine
nine
ten
ten

Comment: map all the values to a LinkedHashMap and then add the values back in list, just this time add only one occurence of first and last duplicates.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far. We don't do your (home)work for you.

Comment: If you are only interested in the elements and not the indices of your first/last elements basically you just print every unique element twice, in other words it makes no sense. What are you exactly trying to achive?

Comment: Why not the first two of duplicate elements? Or the last two? Or the middle two? How would you know the difference? Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] strings = {"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"
            , "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two"
            , "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three", "three"
            , "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four", "four"
            , "five", "five", "five", "five", "five", "five"
            , "six", "six", "six", "six", "six", "six", "six", "six", "six"
            , "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven"
            , "eight", "eight", "eight", "eight", "eight", "eight"
            , "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine"
            , "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten"};

    Map<String,Integer> itemMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String item:strings){
        if(!itemMap.containsKey(item)){
            itemMap.put(item,1);
        }else{
            itemMap.put(item, itemMap.get(item)+1);
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapEntry:itemMap.entrySet()){
        if(mapEntry.getValue()>1){
            System.out.println(mapEntry.getKey()+"\n"+mapEntry.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8, you can use Stream API like this.

```
    Stream.of(strings)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\n" + entry.getKey()));
```